# Connection timout when using Domain name which is mapped to IPv4 address

Tags: c#, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

My Client application on client machines experience a connection time out at some stores when using a DNS name.  Using the IPv4 address instead of the hostname results in an immediate connection.  We have researched this issue and noticed the problem is only seen at the retail stores, looks like the network department has changed their DNS to look for IPv6 address first and then IPv4 address second, this delay seems to be the cause of the connection timeout.

How can I manage this situation in client machine?

Comment: You deploy IPv6 to your server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your application, this clearly is a routing problem imo.